# PHP Include for HTML?

Tags: php, html, include

I have a navigational bar, an image, and a heading that I'll be including in every page of my website, so I wanted to use php include to refer to this code in several pages. However, I think I may have the syntax wrong or something because it's not rendering anything when I load it. Here are some code snippets:

```
<!-- sample page --> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html>  
<head>  
<?php include ('headings.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<?php include ('navbar.php'); ?>
<?php include ('image.php'); ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

navbar.php

```
    <?php 

    echo '<ul id="nav">
        <li>
            <a href="Home.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>About Me</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="Career.html">Career</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Coding.html">Coding</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="Personal.html">Personal</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Travels.html">Travel</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
    </ul>';

    ?>
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: There's no reason to have this in a PHP tag and use `echo`. You can include it even if it's just raw HTML. **Edit**: That said, your code looks fine. Have you tried to view the source, and could you post it in the OP? **Edit**: Perhaps it's because PHP isn't installed on your server, and therefore your browser just renders the PHP tags as regular HTML tags (nothing).

Comment: +1 like you did for the head and body tags

Comment: You might want to consider a template engine instead.  Check out Smarty, Twig, or Dwoo as examples.  There are a ton more out there.

Comment: Can you view the source of the page when you load it? That might deem you with some insight of what actually happens.

Comment: Is your index using the .php extension? Unless you specified another extension to use, you will need the index to be .php and not .htm or .html

Comment: The source of the page after rendering is the exact same as what is in the first code block (<!DOCTYPE, etc). I figured that it might be because PHP isn't installed, but I'm running XAMPP with everything turned on, and it's definitely recognizing PHP because I tried a simple echo statement and it worked properly. @Jeremy, see Edward's post below. I don't think that's true.

Comment: @deathmastar0 is the index with a 'php' extension? Do you see the `<?php include ('headings.php'); ?>` in 'view source'? Are other PHP scripts working in the same folder ?

Comment: @deathmastar0 If your index is .htm it will not process the PHP. You can have PHP with any extension but you must specify this. What is your index's extension? If you are referring to how includes will process PHP, you must first have a PHP file for the includes to work. Since you are on XAMPP I am assuming you have not specified any custom extensions for PHP therefore you must use .php

Comment: @Vatev, what do you mean by "is the index with a 'php' extension"? And yes to the other two questions.

Also, the files are in the directory `C:\xampp\htdocs\website`. So should my filenames in the include statements be `\website\headings.php`? (I tried both, and neither work)

Comment: @deathmastar0 I meant is it `index.php` or `index.html`. I was asking if other scripts are working to determine if you have PHP running at all. If you `include "\website\headings.php"` that will translate to `include "c:\website\headings.php"` and will be obviously wrong. It should work the way you are using it now.

Comment: I currently have it as `index.html`. Does it have to be php? Yeah, PHP's up and running, from what I can tell.

Comment: Yes it has to be .php. That is actually included in 2 of the 3 answers below.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that did it. Sorry, I just got really confused with all the arguments on Edward's post below, when that actually happened to be the root reason... Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use `php` code in files with extension `.php` and only there (iff other is not defined in your server settings).

Just rename your file `*.html` to `*.php`

---

If you want to allow `php` code processing in files of different format, you have two options to do that:

1) Modifying `httpd.conf` to allow this for all projects on your server, by adding:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

2) Creating `.htaccess` file in your separate project top directory with:

```
<Files />
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
</Files>
```

For second option you need to allow use of `.htaccess` files in your `httpd.conf`, by adding the following settings:

```
AllowOverride All
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

*that is correct for Apache HTTP Server

Comment: False. As long as the server is set up to handle different extensions as PHP files, you can include PHP code in a file with **ANY** extension (i.e. `.js`, `.css`, `.html`, etc.).

Comment: You can use PHP in files with other extensions as well.

Comment: Actually you can use PHP wherever you want.

Comment: Okay, iff you set that option in your server settings.

Comment: Most shared servers are only set up to handle php in .php files. Yes, you *can* have it set up otherwise, but come on -- someone who's asking a question at this level probably hasn't gotten that far in figuring out how to do this.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits With include/require it doesn't matter what the filename is. It is always executed as PHP.

Comment: And how you'll include anything into .html document? Maybe just if using SHTML. Or there are ways?

Comment: Finally, I've improved my comment a bit. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits Everything you include from PHP is executed as PHP.

Comment: @Vatev, I mean, you can't include PHP from HTML. Sorry if I've been unclear.

Comment: @Vatev only if the `include` is within a PHP-parseable file (as defined by the server), but I think that goes without saying.

Comment: I think we reached an agreement ~5-6 comments ago :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits, you were right, that was the reason why. I just got really confused when everyone downvoted you so quickly and I figured that that can't be the reason :p

Comment: @deathmastar0 That's the main thing. :) I've just omitted conditions in my answer, so I've been immediately downvoted by vigilant programmers. :P

Comment: How do I access the server settings to enable other?

EDIT: sorry, on second thought, I just realized that it's probably different from server to server.

Comment: You can modify your httpd.conf for allowing setting for all projects running on your server, or use '.htaccess' file for any single project. I'll add "how-to" to my answer in few minutes.

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to be echoing the info within the php file. A php `include` will automatically include any HTML within that file.

Make sure you're actually using a index file with a `.php` extension, `.html` won't work with php includes. (Unless you're telling your server to treat .html files otherwise)

Make sure your paths are correctly set up. From your description, the way you've set it up your header.php/navbar.php/image.php files should be in your root directory.
So your root directory should look like this:

`index.php

navbar.php

image.php

header.php`

Otherwise if those PHP files are in a folder called `/includes/`, it should look like so:

`<?php include ('includes/headings.php'); ?>`

Answer (score 4):

Try to get some debugging information, could be that the file path is wrong, for example.

Try these two things:- 
Add this line to the top of your sample page:

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);?>
```

This will print all errors/warnings/notices in the page so if there is any problem you get a text message describing it instead of a blank page

Additionally you can change include() to require()

```
<?php require ('headings.php'); ?>
<?php require ('navbar.php'); ?>
<?php require ('image.php'); ?>
```

This will throw a FATAL error PHP is unable to load required pages, and should help you in getting better tracing what is going wrong..

You can post the error descriptions here, if you get any, and you are unable to figure out what it means..

Comment: Thanks, but we got it figured out. I'm sure this will be helpful in the future, though!

Answer (score 2):

First: what the others said. Forget the echo statement and just write your navbar.php as a regular HTML file.

Second: your include paths are probably messed up. To make sure you include files that are in the same directory as the current file, use `__DIR__`:

```
include __DIR__.'/navbar.php'; // PHP 5.3 and later
include dirname(__FILE__).'/navbar.php'; // PHP 5.2
```

Answer (score 2):

When the use case is that only include a html page as output, php native method `readfile()` should be called instead. This method simply reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

Usage:

```
readfile(__DIR__ . '/../public/react.html');
exit();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is the step by step process to include php code in html file ( Tested )**

If PHP is working there is only one step left to use PHP scripts in files with *.html or *.htm extensions as well. The magic word is ".htaccess". Please see the Wikipedia definition of .htaccess to learn more about it. According to Wikipedia it is "a directory-level configuration file that allows for decentralized management of web server configuration."

You can probably use such a .htaccess configuration file for your purpose. In our case you want the webserver to parse HTML files like PHP files.

First, create a blank text file and name it ".htaccess". You might ask yourself why the file name starts with a dot. On Unix-like systems this means it is a dot-file is a hidden file.
(Note: If your operating system does not allow file names starting with a dot just name the file "xyz.htaccess" temporarily. As soon as you have uploaded it to your webserver in a later step you can rename the file online to ".htaccess")
Next, open the file with a simple text editor like the "Editor" in MS Windows. Paste the following line into the file:
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm
If this does not work, please remove the line above from your file and paste this alternative line into it, for PHP5:
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .html .htm
Now upload the .htaccess file to the root directory of your webserver. Make sure that the name of the file is ".htaccess". Your webserver should now parse *.htm and *.html files like PHP files.

You can try if it works by creating a HTML-File like the following. Name it "php-in-html-test.htm", paste the following code into it and upload it to the root directory of your webserver:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
     <HTML>
 <HEAD>
 <TITLE>Use PHP in HTML files</TITLE>
 </HEAD>

   <BODY>
    <h1>
    <?php echo "It works!"; ?>
    </h1>
  </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Try to open the file in your browser by typing in: http://www.your-domain.com/php-in-html-test.htm (once again, please replace your-domain.com by your own domain...)
If your browser shows the phrase "It works!" everything works fine and you can use PHP in .*html and *.htm files from now on. However, if not, please try to use the alternative line in the .htaccess file as we showed above. If is still does not work please contact your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a simple solution to the PHP include stuff. Simply rename all your .html files to .php and your're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue. It appears that PHP does not like php code inside included file. In your case solution is quite simple. Remove php code from navbar.php, simply leave plain HTML in it and it will work.