# Modifying the httpd.conf file

Tags: httpd.conf

I'm trying to use a "php include" in a file with an html extension.  I found that same question and the solution here at 'stack' however the answer/solution also included instructions to modify the 'httpd.conf' file by adding this line:

AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

I don't see that "httpd-conf" file anywhere in the file list that's on my hosting server.

This is question/answer/solution entry I'm referencing.

[PHP Include for HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887429/php-include-for-html?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This file is most of the time managed by the web hosting company, not by the hosted users.
Reach to them to see if they can do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can still modify these without access to httpd.conf

Just create a file .htaccess where your php files are (or root of your php application) and place that there:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm .html
```

Please refer to : http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/Htaccess