# If you can't use html inside of php, then why can you call an open ended html script within php tags?

Tags: php, html

If we cannot use html code in php due to the php engine's inability to parse html code, then why can we include an open ended (no closing html tag) html script within php tags?

I've tried replacing the include call with the bare contents of the included file, but this triggers an unexpected end of file error (which makes sense, since php isn't able to parse the html).

**register.php:**

```
<?php
    $page_title = 'Register';
    // the following script echoes $page_title as title, links to stylesheet, and opens body
    include ('includes/header.html');
```

**header.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> <?php echo $page_title ; ?> </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> <h1>Page Header</h1></header>
```

I expected consistency between:

**a)** include('includes/header.html')

and

**b)** simply inserting the header.html code.

Error message from **b)** was standard for when you insert html code within php:

> *Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in C:\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\register.php on line 6*

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? PHP only parses stuff between `<?php ? >` tags. HTML is markup that is parsed by the browser. PHP doesn't care how the browser parses it because by that point the PHP execution is done

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887429/php-include-for-html

Comment: <?php ?> will not work in .html file, either change your file extension to header.php or more your header.html code inside your register.php

Comment: @devpro, I believe that's true for most server configurations -- however, mine appears to be processing the php within the .html file just fine.

Comment: no idea, but try with iframe also. maybe this will solve your problem :)

Comment: I'd put a closing `?>` tag after `include ('includes/header.html');` which I tend to think would resolve this.

Answer (score 5):

`include` is not just some stupid preprocessor macro. It will not simply paste the contents of one file into another. It is a language construct, which will "move into" the other file, process it as it was a file of it's own, while maintaining the context of the parent file.

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
>   mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
>   end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
>   executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid PHP start and end
>   tags. - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

This is also a reason, why you can catch parse errors in the outer file, if the inner file cannot be parsed properly.

Another important nuance is this:

> It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.

This however does not apply to function definitions, which will be processed irregardless of any `return` statements.

The closing PHP tag is only needed if you want to exit PHP mode into HTML in the same file. PHP will exit the PHP mode automatically at the end of every file, even the included ones.

Comment: @devpro Yeah, no. This didn't explain why iframes though. If the server is setup to process .html files with PHP then it has nothing to do with HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to "turn off" PHP when you want to simply output HTML otherwise PHP is going to try and treat it as PHP code and it will fail as you've seen. For the situation you describe the simplest answer is to simply leave PHP while the contents of what were in header.html are output.

```
<?php
    $page_title = 'Register';
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> <?php echo $page_title ; ?> </title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href="includes/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header> <h1>Page Header</h1></header>
<?php # Turn PHP back on for whatever else is in register.php
```